# Generate random number from 1 to 9 and display in 5x5 table in android

Tags: android

Am new in android and have created a layout with 25 textview to display in a table of 5x5 ..i want to display numbers from 1 to 9 but randomly to fit all fields.
this my xml

```
enter code here
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="munene.com.tablegame.MainActivity">

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:columnCount="5"
        android:rowCount="5"
        android:background="@drawable/board">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_column="0"
                    android:layout_row="0"
                    android:text="3"
                    android:id="@+id/one"
                    android:padding="16dp"
                    android:textColor="#fcfbfb"
                    android:textSize="60sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_width="75dp"
                    android:layout_height="97dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_column="0"
                    android:layout_row="0"
                    android:text="5"
                    android:id="@+id/two"
                    android:padding="16dp"
                    android:textColor="#fcfbfb"
                    android:textSize="60sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_width="75dp"
                    android:layout_height="97dp" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_column="0"
                    android:layout_row="0"
                    android:text="9"
                    android:padding="16dp"
                    android:textColor="#fcfbfb"
                    android:textSize="60sp"
                    android:id="@+id/three"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_width="75dp"
                    android:layout_height="97dp" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_column="0"
                    android:layout_row="0"
                    android:text="4"
                    android:id="@+id/four"
                    android:padding="16dp"
                    android:textColor="#fcfbfb"
                    android:textSize="60sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_width="75dp"
                    android:layout_height="97dp" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_column="0"
                    android:layout_row="0"
                    android:text="1"
                    android:id="@+id/five"
                    android:padding="16dp"
                    android:textColor="#fcfbfb"
                    android:textSize="60sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_width="75dp"
                    android:layout_height="97dp" />


            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_column="0"
                    android:layout_row="0"
                    android:text="5"
                    android:id="@+id/six"
                    android:padding="16dp"
                    android:textColor="#fcfbfb"
                    android:textSize="60sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_width="75dp"
                    android:layout_height="97dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_column="0"
                    android:layout_row="0"
                    android:text="8"
                    android:padding="16dp"
                    android:id="@+id/seven"
                    android:textColor="#fcfbfb"
                    android:textSize="60sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_width="75dp"
                    android:layout_height="97dp" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_column="0"
                    android:layout_row="0"
                    android:text="6"
                    android:id="@+id/eight"
                    android:padding="16dp"
                    android:textColor="#fcfbfb"
                    android:textSize="60sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_width="75dp"
                    android:layout_height="97dp" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_column="0"
                    android:layout_row="0"
                    android:text="7"
                    android:id="@+id/nine"
                    android:padding="16dp"
                    android:textColor="#fcfbfb"
                    android:textSize="60sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_width="75dp"
                    android:layout_height="97dp" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_column="0"
                    android:layout_row="0"
                    android:text="2"
                    android:id="@+id/ten"
                    android:padding="16dp"
                    android:textColor="#fcfbfb"
                    android:textSize="60sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_width="75dp"
                    android:layout_height="97dp" />


            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_column="0"
                    android:layout_row="0"
                    android:text="5"
                    android:padding="16dp"
                    android:id="@+id/eleven"
                    android:textColor="#fcfbfb"
                    android:textSize="60sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_width="75dp"
                    android:layout_height="97dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_column="0"
                    android:layout_row="0"
                    android:text="1"
                    android:id="@+id/twelve"
                    android:padding="16dp"
                    android:textColor="#fcfbfb"
                    android:textSize="60sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_width="75dp"
                    android:layout_height="97dp" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_column="0"
                    android:layout_row="0"
                    android:text="4"
                    android:id="@+id/thirteen"
                    android:padding="16dp"
                    android:textColor="#fcfbfb"
                    android:textSize="60sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_width="75dp"
                    android:layout_height="97dp" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_column="0"
                    android:layout_row="0"
                    android:text="9"
                    android:id="@+id/fourteen"
                    android:padding="16dp"
                    android:textColor="#fcfbfb"
                    android:textSize="60sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_width="75dp"
                    android:layout_height="97dp" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_column="0"
                    android:layout_row="0"
                    android:text="4"
                    android:id="@+id/fiveteen"
                    android:padding="16dp"
                    android:textColor="#fcfbfb"
                    android:textSize="60sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_width="75dp"
                    android:layout_height="97dp" />


            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="6dp">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_column="0"
                    android:layout_row="0"
                    android:text="5"
                    android:id="@+id/sixteen"
                    android:padding="16dp"
                    android:textColor="#fcfbfb"
                    android:textSize="60sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_width="75dp"
                    android:layout_height="97dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_column="0"
                    android:layout_row="0"
                    android:text="6"
                    android:id="@+id/seventeen"
                    android:padding="16dp"
                    android:textColor="#fcfbfb"
                    android:textSize="60sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_width="75dp"
                    android:layout_height="97dp" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_column="0"
                    android:layout_row="0"
                    android:text="4"
                    android:id="@+id/eighteen"
                    android:padding="16dp"
                    android:textColor="#fcfbfb"
                    android:textSize="60sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_width="75dp"
                    android:layout_height="97dp" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_column="0"
                    android:layout_row="0"
                    android:text="7"
                    android:id="@+id/nineteen"
                    android:padding="16dp"
                    android:textColor="#fcfbfb"
                    android:textSize="60sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_width="75dp"
                    android:layout_height="97dp" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_column="0"
                    android:layout_row="0"
                    android:text="5"
                    android:id="@+id/twenty"
                    android:padding="16dp"
                    android:textColor="#fcfbfb"
                    android:textSize="60sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_width="75dp"
                    android:layout_height="97dp" />


            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_column="0"
                    android:layout_row="0"
                    android:text="9"
                    android:id="@+id/twentyone"
                    android:padding="16dp"
                    android:textColor="#fcfbfb"
                    android:textSize="60sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_width="75dp"
                    android:layout_height="97dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_column="0"
                    android:layout_row="0"
                    android:text="2"
                    android:id="@+id/twentytwo"
                    android:padding="16dp"
                    android:textColor="#fcfbfb"
                    android:textSize="60sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_width="75dp"
                    android:layout_height="97dp" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_column="0"
                    android:layout_row="0"
                    android:text="3"
                    android:id="@+id/twentythree"
                    android:padding="16dp"
                    android:textColor="#fcfbfb"
                    android:textSize="60sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_width="75dp"
                    android:layout_height="97dp" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_column="0"
                    android:layout_row="0"
                    android:text="1"
                    android:id="@+id/twentyfour"
                    android:padding="16dp"
                    android:textColor="#fcfbfb"
                    android:textSize="60sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_width="75dp"
                    android:layout_height="97dp" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_column="0"
                    android:layout_row="0"
                    android:text="8"
                    android:id="@+id/twentyfive"
                    android:padding="16dp"
                    android:textColor="#fcfbfb"
                    android:textSize="60sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_width="75dp"
                    android:layout_height="97dp" />


            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>


    </GridLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

i want to see how i will display the numbers in the MainActivity referencing a textview fields id

Answer (score 0):

Displaying random in 5x5 must be implemented by yourself. What I can tell you is -

> How to generate random numbers between `min` and `max` -

**Using `java.util.Random` package** -

```
Random random = new Random();
random.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min
```

Let me give you the hint - Use `loops` and generate `random` numbers, add into the `List` or something and display it into you 5x5 stuff.